# C asking for user txt file, saving in array, and outputting in txt

Tags: c, arrays, file, text

So I have a function built already that calculated 25 random temperatures and outputted them and had a max, min, and average feature.  I'm now trying to incorporate input files and output files via txt.

I tried to do some research and plug in what I could (even if I barely understood it), can someone lend some light on my code?

```
int get_value(void);
void calc_results(void);
void read_temps(void);
int sum = 0;
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
int temp[25];
int i = 0;   //For array loop
int j = 0;  //For printf loop
float avg = 0;



void read_temps() {

char fname[128];
printf("Enter .txt file name \n");
scanf("%123s", fname);
strcat(fname, ".txt");
FILE *inputf;
inputf=fopen(fname, "w");

for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){

temp[i] = fname;
sum += temp[i];
}


}

int main () {

calc_results();

return 0;
};


void calc_results(void) {

FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("Output_temps.txt", "w+");

avg = ((sum)/(25));

max = temp[0];
  for(i=1;i<25;i++){
      if(max<temp[i])
           max=temp[i];
        };
min =temp[0];
  for(i=1;i<25;i++){
      if(min>temp[i])
           min=temp[i];
  };

fprintf("Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015 : \n");
fprintf("Time of day     Temperature in degrees F \n");
for(j=0;j<25;j++){
fprintf("  %d                  %d\n",j,temp[j]);
}
fprintf("Maximum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\n", max);
fprintf("Minimum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\n", min);
fprintf("Average Temperature for the day: %.1f Degrees F\n", avg);

fclose(fp);
};
```

Comment: If you are working on Un*X it might be better to have a standard program, and do input and output using file redirection.  In that case read input from **stdin** and output routines need no change.

Comment: `inputf=fopen(fname, "w");` --> `inputf=fopen(fname, "r");` ... `temp[i] = fname;` --> `fscanf(inputf, "%d", &temp[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors in your code, the most critical one being it doesn't compile.  If you're having issues you'll want to follow the instructions for how to make a [ssce](http://sscce.org/).  You will get a much better response this way.  Then explain clearly the specific issue you are having and what it is that is happening or not happening as opposed to what you expect.

With your code you seem to be assigning to your `temp` array the `fname` variable instead of reading in the `int` data from the user file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// assuming you want a maximum of temperatures of 25
#define TEMP_NUMBER 25

// use a struct to maintain and the temparatur data in one place
// without resorting to using global variables or having functions
// that require numerous parameters.
struct temp_data {
    char fname[128];
    int max;
    int min;
    int sum;
    int temps[TEMP_NUMBER];
    float avg;
};

struct temp_data *temps_init(void)
{
    // creates a pointer to struct temp_data to hold
    // your various temparture related fields
    struct temp_data *td = malloc(sizeof *td);

    td->sum = 0;
    td->avg = 0.0;

    return td;
}

void read_temps(struct temp_data *td)
{
    // in your sample code you have this set to "w", needs to be "r"
    FILE *inputf = fopen(td->fname, "r");

    // handle error
    if (!inputf) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TEMP_NUMBER; i++) {
        // you were setting fname to the temparature array
        // instead you need to scan the temp file
        fscanf(inputf, "%d", &(td->temps[i]));
        td->sum += td->temps[i];
    }

}

void print_results(struct temp_data *td)
{
    // a print function to separate logic
    FILE *fp = fopen("Output_temps.txt", "w+");

    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(0);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015 : \n");
    fprintf(fp, "Time of day     Temperature in degrees F \n");

    for(int i=0; i < TEMP_NUMBER; i++) 
        fprintf(fp, "  %d                  %d\n", i, td->temps[i]);

    fprintf(fp, "Maximum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\n", td->max);
    fprintf(fp, "Minimum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F\n", td->min);
    fprintf(fp, "Average Temperature for the day: %.1f Degrees F\n", td->avg);

    fclose(fp);
}

void calc_results(struct temp_data *td)
{
    // do only calculations
    td->avg = td->sum / TEMP_NUMBER;
    td->min = td->temps[0];
    td->max = td->temps[0];

    for (int i=1; i < TEMP_NUMBER; i++) {
        td->min = td->temps[i] < td->min ? td->temps[i] : td->min;
        td->max = td->temps[i] > td->max ? td->temps[i] : td->max;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Moved user input into the main() from read_temps()
    // now read_temps() only needs to read and record the temp data
    struct temp_data *td = temps_init();

    printf("Enter .txt file name \n");
    scanf("%123s", td->fname);
    strcat(td->fname, ".txt");

    read_temps(td);
    calc_results(td);
    print_results(td);

    free(td);

    return 0;
};
```

Using a file called `sample.txt`:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```